# "Can't find crate for `std`" — compiler error with trivial code

Tags: rust

I just updated to latest nightly of rust:

```
> rustc --version
rustc 0.11.0-pre-nightly (05ca9f7 2014-06-24 22:06:48 +0000)
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
```

After that even the trivial program doesn't compile with the following error:

```
> cat main.rs

fn main() {
    print!("Hello world");
}%   

> rustc main.rs 
main.rs:1:1: 1:1 error: can't find crate for `std`
main.rs:1 // Playground
          ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is it some compiler bug in nightly or I didn't grasp some core idea in the language?

Comment: I know nothing of rust, but nightlies are usually far more risky, and if "trivial" code no longer compiles, a bug in the nightly seems exceedingly likely.

Comment: @MooingDuck Nightlies are usually not bad with rust, this is a rare exception. Try one more time with a different nightly. If this still doesn't work, it may mean deeper problems

Comment: FWIW, I'm on Linux (same compiler version) and it worked just fine. Maybe this is osx-specific

Comment: how do you downgrade to an earlier nightly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turned out that if you're upgrading from "semi-stable" version installed with `Homebrew`, you should first uninstall `homebrew` version, and only after that install nightly.

Otherwise you'll face the problems that are described in question: missing system libraries, etc, as rust libraries doesn't use versioning and located in the same place.

Comment: That was *exactly* my problem

Comment: additionally, after removing `homebrew` version of rust, don't forget to uninstall previous rust version you may have, and only then install new using official rust installation script.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this means that there are multiple versions of the standard library lying around. Try reinstalling, or uninstalling and then installing again, to clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error when trying to get Rust to work on a Fedora system using the packages provided by the Fedora repo.

It turns out I too had an old version of Rust installed (via rustup). I did remove it prior to installing the Rust packages with DNF, but I still got the `` error: can't find crate for `std` `` error. [This bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1408435) pointed me in the right direction.

Turns out I had an empty `/usr/lib64/rustlib` directory as a remnant from the previous install (whereas the correct one is `/usr/lib/rustlib`). Removing it resolved the problem.